# Send document to printer from web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I have a webpage that activates a print job on a printer.  This works in the localhost environment but does not work when the application is deployed to the webserver.  I'm using the PrintDocument class from the .net System.Drawing.Print namespace.  I'm now assuming the printer has to be available to the application on the remote server?  Any suggestions on how I would get this to work?

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
PaperSource ps = new PaperSource();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = 
    new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", 1180, 850);
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
                    (this.pd_PrintPage);

// Set your printer's name.  Obtain from
// System's Printer Dialog Box. 
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName =
    "Okidata ML 321 Turbo/D (IBM)";


//PrintPreviewDialog dlgPrintPvw = new PrintPreviewDialog();
//dlgPrintPvw.Document = pd;
//dlgPrintPvw.Focus();
//dlgPrintPvw.ShowDialog(); 

pd.Print();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The printer is on a different computer. `PrintDocument` is for use in desktop applications, not web applications.

To print on the client, you would need to use JavaScript, and you would only be able to print documents already on the client machine. I don't know for sure that there *is* a way to print on the client. You may be able to display a "Print" dialog and have the user print the file himself.

Comment: Further limited than printing "documents already on the client machine" I do believe he'd only be able to print HIS pages, using window.print(); . I don't think javascript could reach out and print any old document on his computer, as this would completely break the sand-boxing model of most browsers.

Comment: How would an intranet application print to a local printer?  That possible?

Comment: What about embedding a Windows Form Control in an asp.net page or using Silverlight?

Comment: @FiveTools: a Windows Forms control or ActiveX control would work in an intranet and not on the Internet. I don't know if Silverlight can print.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues. I was told to put your code inside of this:

```
using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
{
    // code here
}
```

It allows for specific user settings to be used instead of the ASP.NET settings for that particular printer.

This code got it to the printer, but now I'M having issues with multiple copies of one webform hitting the printer.